# Error during the installation of godog on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, go

on ubuntu, when I try to run

```
go get github.com/cucumber/godog/cmd/godog@v0.10.0
```

I receive

```
go: cannot use path@version syntax in GOPATH mode
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need use `$GOPATH` installation way:

```
GO111MODULE=on go get github.com/cucumber/godog/cmd/godog@v0.10.0
```

Mentioned in [README](https://github.com/cucumber/godog#install)

Comment: I ran that with sudo as it wasn't giving me permission to my home directory, and it downloaded the repos.

But when I try to run it on a cucumber test I receive

$ godog -t @Up

Command 'godog' not found, did you mean:

  command 'godoc' from deb golang-golang-x-tools (1:0.0~git20191118.07fc4c7+ds-1)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>

Sorry I'm a noob

Comment: @nocnoc no need for `sudo` probably have issue in your home folder permissions. After installation, you find it at `/home/user/go/bin/godog` . for easier use, add its path to PATH environment varaible.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me
`"export PATH=$(go env GOPATH)/bin:$PATH"`
and try `godog run` again

or

execute the command with the complete path.
in Mac

```
/Users/you_user/go/bin/godog run
```